# Activity Stops responding on Processing Data

Tags: android, dialog

I am developing an activity which have an Update button as menu for android. I want to show a dialog. I done it via
showDialog()
Update operations are controlled by a function named update_rates()
update include downloading file from internet and updating database values
But when i click the menu button it stucks the it download the file and update database.
if I comment the update_rates function it shows dialog but with update_rates it doesn't show dialog
How can i solve this problem?

https://github.com/sreevisakh/android/blob/master/src/com/sv/cc/main.java

Comment: There's no way we can help you without seeing code

Comment: https://github.com/sreevisakh/android/blob/master/src/com/sv/cc/main.java line:183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it never show the dialog? Or does it only show the dialog once it's done it's processing?

To me, it sounds like your update_rates() method is either:

- doing it's work on the UI thread and therefore blocking any subsequent operations (including things like displaying dialogs) until it is complete (so you'd see the dialog afterwards, depending on the ordering of the code).
- not running on the UI thread, but attempting to perform UI actions; which Android does not allow.

If either case is true, then you may want to investigate using AsyncTask to do the work; as this operates in a separate thread, but is also able to perform UI actions.

This article has some more information: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: I am new to android. i am trying to develop a currencyconverter application for studying it. I have no idea about UI and Non UI threads. But can guess something from its names. I doing all the processing in the main activity class is that wrong ? How can i do it in an anothe thread?Here is my code https://github.com/sreevisakh/android/blob/master/src/com/sv/cc/main.java